# Difference in System. exit(0) , System.exit(-1), System.exit(1 ) in Java

Tags: java, system.exit

I'd like to know the difference between the following in Java

```
System.exit(0);
System.exit(-1);
System.exit(1);
```

When do I have to use the above code appropriately?

Comment: why didn't you mark the answer as the 'best answer' so there is a green tick? it helps other people know what the best one is!!

Answer (score 271):

The parameter of exit should qualify if the execution of the program went good or bad. It's a sort of heredity from older programming languages where it's useful to know if something went wrong and what went wrong.

Exit code is

- `0` when execution went fine;
- `1`, `-1`, `whatever != 0` when some error occurred, you can use different values for different kind of errors.

If I'm correct exit codes used to be just positive numbers (I mean in UNIX) and according to range:

- `1-127` are user defined codes (so generated by calling `exit(n)`)
- `128-255` are codes generated by termination due to different unix signals like **SIGSEGV** or **SIGTERM**

But I don't think you should care while coding on Java, it's just a bit of information. It's useful if you plan to make your programs interact with standard tools.

Comment: Also note that an exit code of 0 counts as true in the shell and any other code counts as false. So `java MyApp && echo success` will print "success" iff MyApp has an exit code of 0, i.e. if it calls `exit(0)` or simply reaches the end of the main method without an error.

Comment: Please, always care for the exit code if your app can be used in a script. It is very annoying to have a tool failing silently in the middle of your script (or printing some stack trace and exiting with 0).

Comment: One thing to note: when returning -1, the largest possible positive number is returned in unsigned context (in two's complement representation -1 always sets all bits regardless of number of bytes in the number). So -1 is usually returned when you're returning a non-specific error and don't want it to clash with possible error codes that are already defined and documented. e.g. error code 1 might have been documented as write error; error code 2 might be read error, etc.

Comment: It's a 'sort of heredity' from Unix's *exit(2)` actually.

Answer (score 142):

`Zero` => Everything Okay

`Positive` => Something I expected could potentially go wrong went wrong (bad command-line, can't find file, could not connect to server)

`Negative` => Something I didn't expect at all went wrong (system error - unanticipated exception - externally forced termination e.g. `kill -9`)

*(values greater than 128 are actually negative, if you regard them as 8-bit signed binary, or twos complement)*

There's a load of good [standard exit-codes here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-320/include/sysexits.h)

Comment: "Something I expected to go wrong went wrong" sounds like "Everything Okay".

Comment: "Things that I as the developer can be reasonably expected to anticipate" User Error vs System Error; This is actually covered by top poster: values 128-255 are -ve wrt 8-bit signed binary.

Comment: @tobe It's really more like "Something I expected **could** go wrong went actually wrong" ;)

Comment: Bash treats exit codes as 8-bit unsigned, and will mod 256, so a -1 becomes 255 and 256 becomes 0. Signals (in a kill, e.g. `kill -15`) often result in exit code `128+signal`, but (aside from 9) can be handled and return a different exit code. The `-` in `kill -15` is marks the number as a signal and not a pid, it does not make the signal negative.

Comment: When you do `System.exit(-1)` and then in your shell `echo $?` you get '255'. This is why I said negative numbers are system errors, not because of the '-' in the kill parameter. *Did you seriously think that's what I thought?* But thank you for explaining the mechanism by which Bash constructs these codes.

Comment: @robert I don't know if matthew thought that you thought that, but it might be nice info for those that actually thought that was the case or if they didn't know whether or not it was the case.

Comment: @RikShaaf that's all well and good, but I was concerned that those that actually thought that his remark was right might have though I meant minus when I didn't and in that case what he thought was right was wrong and careless reader might think that I was wrong, thereby ending up being wrong themselves.

Answer (score 58):

`System.exit(system call)` terminates the currently running Java virtual machine by initiating its shutdown sequence. The argument serves as a **status code**.

By convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.

```
  System.exit(0) or EXIT_SUCCESS;  ---> Success
  System.exit(1) or EXIT_FAILURE;  ---> Exception
  System.exit(-1) or EXIT_ERROR;   ---> Error
```

Read More at [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int))

On Unix and Linux systems, `0` for successful executions and `1` or higher for failed executions.

Comment: This answer seem in contradiction with @robert's answer

Comment: It hasn't mentioned in the java doc that exit code -1 represents ERROR instead the wording is "status - Termination status. By convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination."

Comment: `EXIT_*` does not exist in Java.

Answer (score 11):

A non-zero exit status code, usually indicates abnormal termination. if `n != 0`, its up to the programmer to apply a meaning to the various n's.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html.

Answer (score 8):

`exit(0)` generally used to indicate successful termination. `exit(1)` or `exit(-1)` or any other non-zero value indicates unsuccessful termination in general.

Comment: What cofuse me is the argument is passed by coder .Not a return value by the method.How can it indicate the termination result?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer.

```
System.exit(0);// normal termination - Successful - zero
System.exit(-1);//Exit with some Error
System.exit(1);//one or any positive integer // exit with some Information message
```

Answer (score 2):

A good gotcha is any error code > 255 will be converted to error code % 256.
One should be specifically careful about this if they are using a custom error code > 255 and expecting the exact error code in the application logic.
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Answer (score 1):

**System.exit(0)**
by convention, a zero status code indicates successful  termination.

**System.exit(1)**
-It means termination unsuccessful due to some error

Comment: The argument always 'serves as a status code'. Not just when it is zero.

Comment: oh yes . sorry my bad EJP

Answer (score 1):

the difference of the numbers put in system.exit() is explained in other answers. but the REAL DIFFERENCE is that  System.exit() is a code that gets returned to the invoking process. If the program is being invoked by the Operating system then the return code will tell the OS that if system.exit() returned 0 than everything was ok but if not something went wrong, then there could be some handlers for that in the parent process

Answer (score 0):

As others answer `0` meaning success, otherwise.

If you using bat file (window) `System.exit(x)` will effect.

Code java (myapp):

```
if (error < 2){
    help();
    System.exit(-1);    
}
else{
    doSomthing();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

bat file:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
rem -- next command if myapp is success --
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    **String s=null;**
    try {
        System.out.println("Exit");
        System.exit(1);
        **s.length();**
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }finally {
        System.out.println("finally");
    }}
```

Here
**exit(0)** : Generally used to indicate successful termination.
**exit(1) or exit(-1)** or any other non-zero value – Generally indicates unsuccessful termination.
No matter what you pass as an argument, the control flow always comes out and doesn't print anything next, either it may be catch block as **s.length** will throw exception here or finally

Answer (score -10):

```
class calc{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int a, b, c;
    char ch;
    do{

        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.print("1. Addition\n");
                System.out.print("2. Substraction\n");
                System.out.print("3. Multiplication\n");
                System.out.print("4. Division\n");
                System.out.print("5. Exit\n\n");

                System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
                ch=s.next().charAt(0);
                    switch (ch)
                    {
                        case '1' :
                        Addition chose1=new Addition();
                        chose1.add();
                        break;

                        case '2' :
                        Substraction chose2=new Substraction();
                        chose2.sub();
                        break;

                        case '3' :
                        Multiplication chose3= new Multiplication();
                        chose3.multi();
                        break;

                        case '4' :
                        Division chose4=new Division();
                        chose4.divi();
                        break;

                        case '5' :
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;

                        default :
                        System.out.print("wrong choice!!!");
                        break;
                    }
        System.out.print("\n--------------------------\n");                     
    }while(ch !=5); 
}
```

}

In the above code when its System.exit(0); and when i press case 5 it exits properly but when i use System.exit(1); and press case 5 it exits with error and again when i try with case 15 it exits properly by this i got to know that, when ever we put any int inside argument it specifies that, it take the character from that position i.e if i put (4) that it means take 5th character from that string if its (3) then it means take 4th character from that inputed string

Comment: it is reccomended to make the first letter uppercase for the class name.