# When to use system.exit(0)?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in System. exit(0) , System.exit(-1), System.exit(1 ) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434592/difference-in-system-exit0-system-exit-1-system-exit1-in-java)

Can anyboby please explain the use of system.exit(0)?
What will happen internaly when we call this method especially the argument value? 0,1,2,3.. etc

Comment: In addition to the information provided by the answers, the following needs to be added: **do not call `System.exit`** at all unless you **specifically** need the Java process to report an error code. That use case is **exceedingly rare** and most probably you would be calling `System.exit` for no good reason. `System.exit` is a very raw, low-level, and unsafe way to end your program. It `stop`s all threads in the middle of whatever they were doing, giving them no chance to clean up. I have yet to write my first production-quality app that would make use of this call.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 1):

System.exit will ask the VM process to stop, and the code returned will be the code given in parameter. Common codes are: 0 for success, 1 to 127 for error, 128-255 is used by Unix and mapped to signals.

Answer (score 0):

System.exit(int) shuts down the JVM, providing an 'exit code' of 0.

The exit code is the JVM process's return value.

Usually in Unix systems, an exit code of 0 indicates a normal shutdown, and anything that is not zero indicates the shutdown was caused by an error.

See Wikipedia for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

Answer (score 0):

The input to `System.exit` is your error code. A value of 0 means normal exit. A non zero number will indicate abnormal termination. This number can be up to you. Perhaps if you want to exit if you cannot read a file you could use error code =1, if you cannot read from a socket it could be error code = 2.

`System.exit` will terminate the VM and so your  program.

A typical example could be below. If the runMyApp throws an exception where you want to cause the program to exit.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
   try {
      runMyApp();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.exit(1);
   }
}
```