# Repeating a void method

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, repeat

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CollegeTester ct = new CollegeTester();
    ct.getCommand();//goes to command
}   

//Ask user for a command
public void getCommand()
{
    String command = "";
    System.out.println("Enter a command: ");
    command = input.nextLine();
        if(command.equals("add"))
            addCommand();//If command is add go to addCommand
        if(command.equals("course"))
            courseCommand();//If command is course go to courseCommand
        if(command.equals("find"))
            findCommand();
        if(command.equals("remove"))
            removeCommand();
        if(command.equals("highest"))
            highestCommand();
        if(command.equals("login"))
            loginCommand();
        if(command.equals("quit"))
            System.exit(1);
}
```

I want to repeat the getCommand() method until the user types in quit but it always fails

1. i tried to put getCommand() at the end of each other method & if statements it won't repeat
2. i tried to do a while loop for everything but if someone accidently types mistypes quit the program would never end

How would i effectively go back to this method until the user wishes to quit?

Comment: Use correctly a do/while. May you can show your implementation using it?

Comment: do while command != quit? if i press backspace once it goes into an infinite loop

Comment: Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`.

Comment: same thing would happen 
do {
stuff
}while(!(command.equals("quit"));
What would happen is in java if you press backspace the character stays  and so u can never exit program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it one of two ways.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CollegeTester ct = new CollegeTester();
    ct.getCommand();//goes to command

}  

//Ask user for a command
public void getCommand()
{
    boolean exit = false;
    while(!exit){
        String command = "";
        System.out.println("Enter a command: ");
        command = input.nextLine();
            if(command.equals("add")){
                addCommand();//If command is add go to addCommand
            }else if(command.equals("course")){
                courseCommand();//If command is course go to courseCommand
            }else if(command.equals("find")){
                findCommand();
            }else if(command.equals("remove")){
                removeCommand();
            }else if(command.equals("highest")){
                highestCommand();
            }else if(command.equals("login")){
                loginCommand();
            }else if(command.equals("quit")){
                exit = true;
            }else {
                System.out.println("Not valid command, try again.");
            }
    }

}



//Ask user for a command
public void getCommand()
{
    while(true){
        String command = "";
        System.out.println("Enter a command: ");
        command = input.nextLine();
            if(command.equals("add"))
                addCommand();//If command is add go to addCommand
            if(command.equals("course"))
                courseCommand();//If command is course go to courseCommand
            if(command.equals("find"))
                findCommand();
            if(command.equals("remove"))
                removeCommand();
            if(command.equals("highest"))
                highestCommand();
            if(command.equals("login"))
                loginCommand();
            if(command.equals("quit"))
                System.exit(0);  // or could use 'break' here (thanks Mikkel)
    }

}
```

Edit:  Corrected System.exit(1).  Thanks Mikkel.

Comment: Alternatively you can just `break` out of the `while(true)` loop. Also `System.exit()` should be called with 0, to indicate a clean exit.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can place it inside a while loop:

```
while(true) {
    getCommand();
}
```

Also, check out [this question on System.exit(int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434592/difference-in-system-exit0-system-exit-1-system-exit1-in-java), you are effectively saying that the application should close because of an error. When it's intended to close, you ought to pass `0`, not `1`.

In fact, if you use a while loop like above, I might just escape the loop through a `return false;` or something and let the program end naturally.