# Fatal exception handling in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a basic math parser with Java and doing this is revealing my shallow understanding of Java exception handling.

when I have this input:

```
String mathExpression = "(3+5";
```

and I subsequently call:

```
throw new MissingRightParenException();
```

the IDE forces me to surround with a try/catch like so:

```
             try {
                    throw new MissingRightParenException();
                } catch (MissingRightParenException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
```

however, in order to force this to be a fatal exception, it looks like I have to add my own code to call `System.exit()`, like so:

```
             try {
                    throw new MissingRightParenException();
                } catch (MissingRightParenException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
```

I am not sure I understand the syntax behind all of this, especially why I have to use a try/catch block around throwing an exception.

what is the rhyme and reason behind this?

Instead of throwing the exception, I could do this instead:

```
new MissingRightParenException();
```

instead of calling

```
throw new MissingRightParenException();
```

**so I guess my question is - if this is a fatal exception, what is the best way to make it truly fatal while giving the user the best feedback?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have a *checked exception* that you have to catch - but not right away - then you can define `throws MissingRightParenException` in the signature of your methods.

```
class MissingRightParenException extends CalculationException {
    ...
}

class CalculationException extends Exception {
    ...
}

class MyClass {

    int myMathRelatedMethod(String calculation) throws CalculationException {
        ...
        if (somethingWrong) {
            throw new MissingRightParenException("Missing right paren for left paren at location: " + location);
        }
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {        
        ...
        try {
            myMathRelatedMethod(args[0]);
        } catch (CalculationException e) {
            // stack trace not needed maybe
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also define it as the *cause* of a `RuntimeException` but that doesn't seem a good match for your current problem.

```
try {
     ...
     throw new MissingRightParenException();
     ...
} catch (MissingRightParenException e) {
     // IllegalStateException extends (IS_A) RuntimeException
     throw new IllegalStateException("This should never happen", e);
}
```

If your `MissingRightParenException` class extends `RuntimeException` then you don't have to catch it. The message will fall through all methods where it (or it's parent classes such as `Throwable`, `Exception` and `RuntimeException`) is not explicitly caught. *You should however not use `RuntimeException`s for input related errors.*

Usually the user will get the stack trace or at least the error message, although that depends of course or the error handling further down the line. Note that even `main` does not have to handle exceptions. You can just specify `throws Exception` for the `main` method to let the console receive the stack traces.

So in the end: use `throws` in the signature of your methods instead of catching exceptions before you want to handle them.

Comment: PS the first thing I do when configuring my IDE is replacing the `e.printStackTrace()` with `// TODO handle exception correctly` followed by `throw new IllegalStateException("Exception not yet correctly handled", e);`. You won't "fall through" and it therefore doesn't mess up your control flow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your exception is currently a subclass of Exception, which is a Checked Exception, you need to handle in a try catch. If you can make your exception a RunTimeException, you no longer need to do the try-catch stuffs.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the best way to make it truly fatal while giving the user the
>   best feedback?

Personally, I don't think a missing parenthesis should be a Fatal exception. The user should have the possibility to re-try.

However, if you really want to know, It is not possible with `java` to create a custom fatal exception as fatal exception means something went wrong on the system/jvm, not on the program itself. Still, you should change `System.exit(0)` to `System.exit(1)` or anything not equal to `0` as a program exiting with 0 as error code mean everything went right which is not the definition of an exception.

> I am not sure I understand the syntax behind all of this

Basically what you do here is throw an exception so you have two choices, either catch it or re-throw it but anyway it will have to be caught somewhere. Then in the `catch` you simply end the program returning an error code meaning that something failed `System.exit(1)`

See this [Difference in System. exit(0) , System.exit(-1), System.exit(1 ) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434592/difference-in-system-exit0-system-exit-1-system-exit1-in-java) for a better understanding of error code.

Answer (score 1):

If `MissingRightParenException` is a checked exception (that seems to be the case, otherwise your IDE wouldn't be "nagging") then either you have to wrap it inside a `try ... catch` block or declare it via a `throws` clause in the method definition. The latter allows you to "bubble up" the exception and catch in the caller of your method throwing the `MissingRightParenException` exception.

Did you think about a `throws` clause?