# Is it possible to stop execution of finally block?

Tags: java, exception, finally

This doesn't makes any sense still i am curious to know if it is possible to stop execution of **finally block** in java? If yes, how?
Say for example the below code:

```
public class Foo 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        { 
            return; 
        } 
        finally 
        {
            System.out.println( "Yes, I executed successfully." ); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I want the output on the console will not as **Yes, I executed successfully.**

> Well that seems to be possible I concluded. All answers have something
>   different to accept that it is possible. So, I am not accepting any
>   answer specifically. Refer them to reach to conclusion as according to your satisfaction. Thanks to all
>   who posted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JLS §14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)

> A `try` statement with a `finally` block is executed by first executing
>   the `try` block. Then there is a choice:
>
> - If execution of the `try` block completes normally, then the `finally` block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the `finally` block completes normally, then the `try` statement completes normally.
>   - If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason `S`, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason `S`.
> - If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value `V`, then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the run-time type of `V` is assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any `catch` clause of the `try` statement,
>       then the first (leftmost) such `catch` clause is selected. The value `V`
>       is assigned to the parameter of the selected `catch` clause, and the
>       Block of that `catch` clause is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>     - If the `catch` block completes normally, then the `finally` block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>       - If the `finally` block completes normally, then the `try` statement completes normally.
>       - If the `finally` block completes abruptly for any reason, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>     - If the `catch` block completes abruptly for reason `R`, then the `finally` block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>       - If the `finally` block completes normally, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason `R`.
>       - If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason `S`, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason `S` (and reason `R` is
>           discarded).
>   - If the run-time type of `V` is not assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any `catch` clause of the `try` statement,
>       then the `finally` block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>     - If the `finally` block completes normally, then the `try` statement completes abruptly because of a throw of the value `V`.
>     - If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason `S`, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason `S` (and the throw of value
>         `V` is discarded and forgotten).
> - If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly for any other reason `R`, then the `finally` block is executed, and then there is a
>     choice:
>
>   - If the `finally` block completes normally, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason `R`.
>   - If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason `S`, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason `S` (and reason `R` is
>       discarded).

In short, if the JVM does not exit (via `System.exit`) then the `finally` block is **always** run.

But the `finally` block may exit abnormally, for example by throwing an exception, in this case the `finally` block will only be partly executed.

Comment: It is *run*, but may not *complete normally*.

Comment: And if there is a case such that death of thread occurs, then in that case will finally block execute?

Comment: `ThreadDeath` is the name of the exception thrown by the thread which was ordered to stop.

Comment: Means if a thread stopped using **ThreadDeath **, still the finally will execute?

Comment: @choxx [`Thread.stop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) throws an exception - `finally` would still run. [`Thread.destroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) - I'm actually not sure, but I presume that the `finally` won't run. Both of these methods are long deprecated however.

Comment: `ThreadDeath` occurring *within* `finally` will curtail its execution and cause it to complete abprutly. This is the concern.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik but that's not really a `finally` block problem, but the core reason that these methods were deprecated - the `Thread`drops all monitors and just...goes away. Not as bad as `destory` however...

Answer (score 2):

```
1. A infinite loop above it will stop its execution
2. System.exit() above it will stop it
```

Comment: Yeah, pretty different case you give above, ** A infinite loop above it will stop its execution**. Awesome..

Comment: An infinite loop definitely doesn't stop the execution of the `finally` block. The block just goes on executing indefinitely long. More importantly, no code following `finally` ever gets executed.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't come across situation where you practically need. But Its typical interview question and answer is

```
   System.exit(0)
```

See
[Difference in System. exit(0) , System.exit(-1), System.exit(1 ) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434592/difference-in-system-exit0-system-exit-1-system-exit1-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.stop()` causes an exception to be thrown in the target thread. This happens asynchronously and may just as well happen while executing a `finally` block. In that case the `finally` block will complete abruptly, but the thread where it happened is allowed to continue execution.

```
try {
  try {
    ...code...
  } finally { 
     ...resource cleanup, ThreadDeath thrown here...
  }
} catch (ThreadDeath t) {
  System.out.println("Thread was ordered to stop, ignoring.");
}
```

Comment: In this case finally block will execute if i am not wrong!

Comment: It will *start* executing, but may never execute a single instruction. Specifically, your `System.out.println()` may never execute.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) says it best:

> Note: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.

However, the return statement in the try will not prevent the finally block from executing.  Nor would throwing an exception.  This behavior is in why the finally block exists in the first place.  It lets you reliably clean up resources.

Comment: you mean to say that there are chances in an application that execution continues even if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, and the finally block may not execute?

Comment: In a multi-threaded application yes. Though "chance" is misleading.  Something would have to deliberately kill the thread.

Comment: well thanks for your answer, but if possible can you give me a link or example for showing that case i said in above comment?