# return after System.exit() statement in java

Tags: java, return

I want to terminate my program when input is `5`.

My program doesn't close while pressing 5.

***Code snippet:***

```
System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
System.out.println("1. Go north");
System.out.println("2. Go east");
System.out.println("3. Go south");
System.out.println("4. Go west");
System.out.println("5. Quit");
System.out.print("Enter command (1-5): ");
// get and return the user's selection
System.exit(0); // exit the menu
return s.nextInt();
```

How to change it any suggestions?

Comment: `return s.nextInt();` --> is *unreachable code*

Comment: Do you know what `System.exit(0)` does?

Comment: Actually I tried System.exit(5); but got confused

Comment: @Nachinne_Manche That comment made me laugh. In all seriousness, have you tried an `if`-statement?

Comment: tried but was unable to make it... can you do it for me???

Answer (score 5):

You are exiting the program before getting any input from the user.

Remove

```
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

The evil place is here;

> System.exit(0); // exit the menu

But it exit full program execution. Just comment this line and you will see user input.

For more info follow the links:

- [When should we call System.exit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715967/when-should-we-call-system-exit-in-java)
- [Difference in System. exit(0) , System.exit(-1), System.exit(1 ) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434592/difference-in-system-exit0-system-exit-1-system-exit1-in-java)

***Update:***

You able to add `if()` condition for terminating program when user enter `5`:

```
int input = Integer.parseInt(s.nextInt());
if (input == 5) {
   System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I want to exit the program after pressing 5

Comment: @Nachinne_Manche You have to parse from String input to int. I updated it.

Comment: @Nachinne_Manche it's kind of you "accept" the answer that resolved your issue, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The below line doesnt exit the menu rather terminates the program execution

```
System.exit(0); // exit the menu
```

so other parts of your code becomes un-reachable

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) to exit on pressing 5 -

```
switch (int){
   case 1:
     //code for go north
    break;
 .
 . 
 .
 case 5:
    System.exit(0);
    break;

 default:
   break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.exit(int status) --> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine.

After this statement we cannot execute other statements.

In your code you are using System.exit(0) before return statement.