# why the ParseException appears when use SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parseexception

I wrote the code below with eclipse:

```
String d = "2014-6-1 21:05:36";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");        
Date date =sdf.parse(d);        
System.out.print(date);
```

and the line 4 throws an `Unhandled exception type ParseException.`

But if I write:

```
try {
  String d = "2014-6-1 21:05:36";   
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");        
  Date date =sdf.parse(d);      
  System.out.print(date);
} catch(ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.print("you get the ParseException");
}
```

or add `throws ParseException` at the beginning of main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
  String d = "2014-6-1 21:05:36";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");        
  Date date =sdf.parse(d);      
  System.out.print(date);
}
```

They all work well... What's wrong with my code? I use the method `printStackTrace()` at the catch block, but why can't I see the ParseException?

Comment: it is telling you that SimpleDateFormat's parse says it could throw that exception.  it doesn't mean that it did.  The compiler wants you to either handle it, or acknowledge it is a possibility by marking your method as possibly being a source of this exception.

Comment: You have a different format in case 2, the one where you print the exception.

Comment: I'm fairly sure your third excerpt there _doesn't_ work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about you actually getting an exception. But it's possible that your String is in the wrong format (which it is not). In that case you would get an exception.

So the compiler wants you to handle that exception. You either have to rethrow it or catch it. BUT: You won't actually get the exception with your code. It's just in case there ever is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In any **IDE** (Integrated Development Environment), editor show the compile type error that will be unresolved at compile-time.

What you are observing the behavior of IDE in your case, at `sdf.parse(d);`means it can throw an parse exception at runtime, So you have to handle it accordinly. Otherwise program will be crashed.

In second code snippet of yours, It will catch an parse exception when occured and show you the exception `e.printStackTrace();` for your record and code will not crash, i.e. `exit(0)` or `exit(1)` with error, [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434592/difference-in-system-exit0-system-exit-1-system-exit1-in-java)

While in last code snippet of yours, method is been decleared that it may throw an exception, So if it called from any other source, this should be handled, say try catch.

You can use any of the two solution, its just your choice.

**more**

following is the method signature in `SimpleDateFormat`

```
public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException
```

So this throws indicates that when this method is been called this must be handled