# JMeter Scripts - Stop All Thread Groups (Entire Test) based on a condition

Tags: groovy, jmeter, threadgroup

I have a JMeter script with multiple thread groups which are running concurrently. In one thread group `PostProcessor`, I would like to check for a condition and stop **ALL** thread groups, and exit. Basically, I want to stop the entire test.

```
if (Integer.valueOf(prev.getResponseCode()) >= 400) {
    // Stop the entire test in the next line.   
}
```

How can I stop all thread groups at once, in a JMeter Script?

Please see:

- My JMeter version: 5.3
- Groovy version: 3.0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers with status codes above 400 as failed so you don't have to go for scripting, you can stop the test using [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) using the following condition:

```
${__jexl3("${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}"=="false",)}
```

and add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as a child of the If Controller

[image]

If you want to do this in Groovy - go for one of the following approaches:

- `prev.setStopTest(true)`  - to gracefully "ask" threads to stop
- `prev.setStopTestNow(true)` - to forcefully "tell" threads to stop (you might get extra errors connected with abnormal threads interruption)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [prev](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to [stop test](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

```
 prev.setStopTestNow(true);
```

> stop the test now interrupting current running samplers

> prev - (SampleResult) - gives access to the previous SampleResult (if any)

For a more sudden and abnornal exit, you can [exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434592/difference-in-system-exit0-system-exit-1-system-exit1-in-java) Java process

```
 System.exit(1);
```